# Python script doesn't return values altough program runs correctly interactively(windows10 cmd)

Tags: python-3.x, windows

I have set up the PATH variable to python, so that I can run python scripts from windows 10 cmd. It mostly works fine, until I run the code below: it does not return any value.
 I have to note that it works if I use python interactively and it definetly works on Linux.

[image: python ran interactively vs script]

```
 def fib2(n):
    result=[]
    a,b=0,1
    while a<n:
        result.append(a)
        a,b=b,a+b
    return result

fib100=fib2(100)
fib100
```

It should show :
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
Instead the output is blank.

Note: this Program is meant to work without function print(). As I mentioned, this already runs interactively, it is more likely a windows problem.

2nd Edit: I have just learned that this cannot function without print, the reason it is printed interactively is merely for convenience so this is not possible without print() in a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use print function in the last line:

```
print(fib100)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the function [print()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) to show the output in the console.

```
 def fib2(n):
    result=[]
    a,b=0,1
    while a<n:
        result.append(a)
        a,b=b,a+b
    return result

fib100=fib2(100)
print(fib100)
```